# Magento Oauth Adminhtml controller class Override

Tags: magento

I want to Override magento core controller class which is present under 'Oauth' module.
Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php

Module declaration xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <DS_Adminextended>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </DS_Adminextended>
    </modules>
</config>
```

My config.xml is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules> 
        <DS_Adminextended> 
            <version>1.0.0</version> 
        </DS_Adminextended> 
    </modules>
                         
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <DS_Adminextended before="Mage_Adminhtml">DS_Adminextended</DS_Adminextended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

i had also use this one but invain:

```html
<modules>
 <DS_Adminextended before="Mage_Adminhtml">DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml_Oauth</DS_Adminextended>
 </modules>
```

and extended AuthorizeController.php :

```html
<?php

 require_once("Mage/Oauth/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php");

die('bla bla bla');

class DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml_Oauth_AuthorizeController extends Mage_Oauth_Adminhtml_Oauth_AuthorizeController {
 
 public function indexAction()
 {
 echo 'extendedController';exit;
 $this->_initForm();
 $this->_initLayoutMessages($this->_sessionName);
 $this->renderLayout();
 }
}
```

But it did not include the extended file.
This 'Adminhtml' present inside the Mage/Oauth Folder not in Mage:Adminhtml
So Question is how we can extend admin controller class present under non admin module like:
1) Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
OR
2) Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/Widget/InstanceController.php

what i am missing in above code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

```html
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <DS_Adminextended before="Mage_Oauth">DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml</DS_Adminextended>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

This is the correct config file if you want to extend admin module not present in Mage::admin
magic is here:

```html
<modules><DS_Adminextended before="Mage_Oauth">DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml</DS_Adminextended></modules>
```

you have to place "Mage_Oauth" in before instead to "Mage_Adminhtml" even if its appearing in adminhtml. secondly 
path to controller call should be "**DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml**" not even if your base contrroller have one more directory inside like in my case as per core directory '**DS_Adminextended_Adminhtml_Oauth**' .

Hope this will help someone and save time, please rank up if it help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake in the require_once path and missed the controllers directory.
Try

```
require_once 'Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php';
```

Comment: Its typo mistake I used:
 require_once("Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php");

Issue is:  its not including My extended file , control not goes to extended file.
i had placed 
die('bla bla bla');
I am not receiving this print. also if controll goes to my file even then I can receive fatal error for including file as you mentioned the error for path.

I think having issue in config.xml  but unable to find it